# Django start from scratch

Tags: django, django-forms, django-cms

I am a PHP developer and know about all the major frameworks like Joomla!, CI, zend etc.

Now I got a project in Python based CMS ( DJango ).

I am studying python now a days and I had some doubts.

1. Can I set wamp ( I mean apache ) for running platform of DJango ?
   If yes please suggest me any doc / tutorial for setting up wamp
2. Is Django a MVC architecture frame word ?
3. Like in Joomla! is it having any authentication system ?

Where to start Django from scratch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no need to setup apache since django comes with built-in server for development. But still if you want to setup apache, you can try [bitnami django-stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack).
2. Yes. Django is a MVC architecture based framework. I found this [django-faq-question](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names) useful.
3. Yes. Django is having its built-in authentication system in the module named `auth`. More information about this can be found in [django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

To start writing your first django app, refer the clear documentation given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: ok thanks for your reply .. and I had one more doubt .. how to deploy the application in server like we are doing in php ? means just copy the files in to the server is enough ? plz help

Comment: Its depends on the hosting service you are using. I have been using webfaction. Just uploading the files is not enough. You need to do some server side configuration like setting up `admin_media` and `static_media`. You can find a [demo by webfaction here](http://www.webfaction.com/demos/django).

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply and I am planning this as an internal ( intranet ) office application. So that I think I can skip these steps  Am I correct ?

Comment: You are correct. I think those setups are not required for an intranet setup. But I don't have idea about intranet setup in django. You can refer the [article here](http://www.davidfischer.name/2009/10/using-django-for-intranet-applications/) and the [python-package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-intranet/0.4) here.